# Add entry author meta field in entries listing table in CP?

Tags: entries-field, author

In CP Craft Admin in the entries table view I d like to display some authors meta info.
How could I do that in my plugin?
I know `public function modifyEntryTableAttributes(&$attributes, $source)` and `public function getEntryTableAttributeHtml(EntryModel $entry, $attribute)`and but I cannot make it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track with both of those. First, [modifyEntryTableAttributes](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/hooks-reference#modifyEntryTableAttributes).

> Gives plugins a chance to modify the table columns shown on the entry index page.

This lets you name the column for your author info. It's a [hook](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/hooks-and-events#hooks), so you'll need to add a public method with the same name as that that to your main plugin class. You can also limit the column to particular section by checking the `$source` variable.

```
public function modifyEntryTableAttributes(&$attributes, $source)
{
    if ($source == 'section:3')
    {
        $attributes['author'] = Craft::t('Author');
    }
}
```

Then to actually return the information, you need [getEntryTableAttributeHtml](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/hooks-reference#getEntryTableAttributeHtml).

> Gives plugins a chance to customize the HTML of the table cells on the entry index page.

Here you can just check for the attribute you set above, and return a string.

```
public function getEntryTableAttributeHtml(EntryModel $entry, $attribute)
{
    if ($attribute == 'author')
    {
        return $entry->getAuthor()->getFriendlyName();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes thats right answer. I had it but it was not working because of a conflict with DashCols plugin indeed. So I disabled the plugin and it works great. Now I just know that its DashCols plugin or all custom made. One way or the other... not both.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand I think the methods you reference are for when you create a plugin with its own custom element type, I don't think you can interact with the entry listing as standard without a plugin.

I do think there is a plugin which might help you achieve this though without having to write your own.

https://github.com/mmikkel/DashCols-Craft/

From the looks of things this should let you add custom fields to the entry listing page, I haven't actually used this but it looks solid.

Comment: I use it all the time but in my case its useless because I want a field from a relationTo entry (the author of the entry)... Not possible with DashCols.